# Internet explorer 8 not working fine when deploying on weblogic 10

Tags: html, internet-explorer, jsf-2.2, weblogic-10.x

I have a sample crud application deployed as .war on weblogic 10.3.6 using JSF , hibernate and .HTML for views

Issue:

When running the app on internet explorer 8 Jsf actions at buttons are not working, also redirection on hyperlinks are not working, only the home page at the app is rendered and nothing else is responding.

But when running the app at Firefox or chrome every thing is working normally and all actions are working fine.

Also when deploying on glassfish 3.4 every thing is working normally on internet explorer or Firefox.

Any one knows what's going wrong when deploying on weblogic and running on internet explorer???

Comment: You know that IE8 does not support html5, do you? Encourage **everyone** that still uses it to drop it...

Comment: Thanks @kukeltje, I tried to run on IE 10 or 11 I faced the same issue when deploying at weblogic 10, but when deploying at glassfish 3.4 the app is working normally on IE 10 or 11!!

Comment: So the title of your question is wrong?

Comment: @Kukeltje  If IE8 not supporting html5 , why it's with ng normal with the same app web deploying on glassfish

Comment: Maybe because that is not html5?

Comment: And maybe using it from a different server makes IE switch to compatiblity mode...

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer 8 [isn't supported anymore](http://thenextweb.com/microsoft/2016/01/05/web-developers-rejoice-internet-explorer-8-9-and-10-die-on-tuesday/)

Comment: Thanks @joaumg, but I facing same issue with IE 10 and 11, is it a compatibility issue between weblogic and IE ??, because IE 10 & 11 is working normally when running at glassfish